# Replace a string fails in some cases

Tags: javascript, regex

I must check a string and replace something of them.

I have to check if

```
$mystring='abc...';
```

has one of this values px,em,%,vh,s

I use this to check the string

```
function replaceUnit(input){ return input.replace(/(px|em|%|vh|s)/i ,'') }
```

It works but produces error in some cases.

If I have in my string for example

```
$mystring="its embeded"
```

The function will replace the "s" and "em" that's not the way it should be.

The function should check if in mystring is

```
only a number+px
or only a number+em
or only a number+%
or only a number+vh
or only a number+s
```

If there is a match, the function should replace the textpart, in all other cases the function should do nothing.

Is it possible to create a kind of this function and how a replace code must be?

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE

based on one of the answears i trie to change it

```
var input="0s";
function replaceUnit(input)
{ 
  console.log('check: '+input); 
  var test=input.replace(/(\d)(?:px|em|%|vh|s)$/i ,''); 
  console.log('->: '+test); 
  return test  
}
```

the result in the console is

```
check: 0s 
->:
```

Comment: `/[0-9]+/(px|em|%|vh|s)/` or `/(px|em|%|vh|s)$/` Shoudl work

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54305031/edit) then click the `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] with actual examples and expected output

Comment: If you want to replace the unit just use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`. If the string begins with numerical values it will trim the ending non-numeric characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `$` (end-of-string anchor) to the end of the regular expression, to ensure that it'll only match if the characters occur at the very end, and capture a number before those characters, so that you can replace with that number alone (thus stripping out the extra characters):

```
return input.replace(/(\d)(?:px|em|%|vh|s)$/i ,'$1')
```

https://regex101.com/r/IodB6z/1

Comment: at first, thanks a lot for helping. I trie with your code "input.replace(/(\d)(?:px|em|%|vh|s)$/i ,'')" but it delete the number in my case of "0s" i get a empty result!?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, it results in `0` for me https://regex101.com/r/IodB6z/2

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] if it seems to be deleting the numbers, so we can see what the problem is and try to debug it

Comment: i've update my post with my code, please have a look

Comment: See the code in my answer - it's not replacing with the empty string, it's replacing with the first captured group (with the digit, as the text explains) - use `'$1'`, not `''`

Comment: oh i thought it was a kind of placeholder for the replacement variable, but in a way, it is, but not in such way, i know - thanks a lot!